# how to extract form fields with koa

Tags: koa

I am having trouble extracting form fields in koa:

Say I send a form like this:

```
<form action="/somewhere" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="somefield"/>
</form>
```

How can I extract these on the backend:

```
  router.post('/somewhere', async ctx => {
    const { form } = ctx.req; //not here

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some middleware to parse the request body. Check out [`koa-bodyparser`](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser). You can use it like so:

**app.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const router = require('./routes')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(bodyParser()) // Make sure you `use` bodyParser before your router
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())
```

**routes.js**

```
const Router = require('koa-router')

const router = new Router()

router.post('/somewhere', async ctx => {
  console.log(ctx.request.body.somefield); // All your form fields will be available on the `ctx.request.body` object
})
```